# Mongo findById() only works sometimes even when passed a valid ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud

I am having a strange issue querying a Mongo DB collection. I am using `findById()` to get a single item that works sometimes and not others.

I have checked the id being passed to the server route and in all cases, they match perfectly with the targeted document in the collection.

Here is the basic code:

```
router.get("/:postId", async (req, res) => {
  console.log('id : ', req.params.postId)
  console.log('type: ', typeof(req.params.postId)) // id is a string
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postId).exec();
    console.log('post :', post) // sometimes null
    res.json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

In the above route, only certain posts will be found while others come back `null`. This happens regardless of whether the id passed is correct and the document exists with the exact id.

If anyone has any ideas about what could be going wrong here I'd much appreciate the help!

**EDIT**

I have done some more debugging and think it is something to do with the Schema for the Post model.

For example, this object will be found:

```
{
"tags": ["foo"],
"_id": "8394839483fhg020834903",
"title": "bar",
"content": "baz",
"isPrivate": true,
}
```

But this one will not because of the missing `isPrivate` property.

```
{
"tags": [],
"_id": "5e0fdc631ef5c46b285a4734",
"title": "New post",
"content": "Some content here",
}
```

I have tested this across multiple queries and it appears to the root of the problem.

I have tried adding

```
isPrivate: {
    required: false
  }
```

To the Schema but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Here is the full Schema

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tags: [{ type: String }],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  isPrivate: {
    type: Boolean
    required: false
  }
});
```

I'm not a Mongo/Mongoose expert, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: So if you pass the correct ID, you get valid result and other times it returns `null`? I mean isn't that how it's supposed to work? Am I missing something!?!

Comment: @ShivamSood No, let's say I make two requests, for different posts and both have their correct id. One will return a post and just other might not, despite being in the collection and the id being correct. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Answer (score 0):

If post id match with any record it return data, otherwise it will return null. You should handle the exception

```
router.get("/:postId", async (req, res) => {
   try {
     const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postId).exec();
     if(post) {
       return res.json(post);
     }
     res.json({ message:'No Post found' });
   } catch (err) {
     res.json({ message: err });
   }
});
```

You can manually check is record exists against a post id. You can use MongoDB Compass for gui browse the record

Comment: This is not the problem. I know the record exists and that the id is correct(can see it in the DB), yet the request might still return null. I know the query works because it will return some other posts without any issue.

Comment: Have you add _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId } to schema

Comment: Tried this too. It doesn't solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue might be with your `_id` as per mongo standard `_id` should be a String is of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.

We can check if the `_id` is valid using `mongoose.isValidObjectId()`

I did run this check on your objects that you posted and indeed 1 is invalid while other is valid

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

console.log(`is '8394839483fhg020834903' valid - ${mongoose.isValidObjectId('8394839483fhg020834903')}`);
console.log(`is '5e0fdc631ef5c46b285a4734' valid - ${mongoose.isValidObjectId('5e0fdc631ef5c46b285a4734')}`);
```

It gives me[image: Valid/Invalid]

You will have to check what is modifying your ID's in the code, you can upload your schema to get a better understanding as well.

Comment: The above ID  that comes back false is not an actual ID. I just typed it out as a placeholder for a quick example. The actual IDs are not being transformed in any way before the query is made. Sorry about that. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: If you can post your schema I can look into it further.

Comment: I added the schema to the end of my question. Thanks!